# create second pdf page if previous one is full

Tags: android, pdf, document

I am creating a pdf document in my application of A4 size, I want to draw my text on that page, but when the text is much larger then it will all the area of the page and rest of the text didn't got drawn on the page , so I want to achieve that if my first page is create another page and draw the rest of the text on another page. can some one please help me??

My code is

```
public void create_Pdf_File(String text, String filename) {

    Typeface font = scanEditText.getTypeface();


    PdfDocument pdf_doc = new PdfDocument();

    try {

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Scanned Documents/pdf file/";


        File pdf_dir = new File(path);

        if(!pdf_dir.exists())
            pdf_dir.mkdirs();


        File pdf_file = new File(pdf_dir,  filename + ".pdf");
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(pdf_file);

        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new             PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(595, 842, 1).create();
        PdfDocument.Page page = pdf_doc.startPage(pageInfo);

        Paint myPaint = new Paint();
        myPaint.setTypeface(font);


        int x = 10, y = 25;


        for(String line : text.split("\n")) {

            page.getCanvas().drawText(line, x, y, myPaint);
            y += myPaint.descent() - myPaint.ascent();

        }

        pdf_doc.finishPage(page);
        pdf_doc.writeTo(fout);
        pdf_doc.close();

        Toast.makeText(this, "saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    catch(Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: Post your code block for creating PDF documents

Comment: I have mentioned the code above please help me

Comment: In your code you have `page = pdf_doc.startPage(pageInfo)` and `pdf_doc.finishPage(page)`. Have you tried finishing the previous page and creating a new one once in your loop the **y** position gets low enough...

Comment: If the text is long and you need to automatically create the next page when text limit ends or prevent the text from overflowing, then what you can do is limit the number of characters in a particular page. Firstly you have to divide the long text according to the number of character in that page, loop through it and print. **Check my answer where I have explained with sample code how to handle it.** https://stackoverflow.com/a/71394812/12552434

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below snippet. Read comments between code

```
   //...
   //...
   int x = 10, y = 25;
   String[] lines = text.split("\n"); 
   for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        // Check if drawing is close to the end of page
        if(842 - y < 40)page = getNextPage(pdf_doc,page);
        page.getCanvas().drawText(lines[i], x, y, myPaint);
        y += myPaint.descent() - myPaint.ascent();
       //Check if last line in loop
       if(i == lines.length - 1) pdf_doc.finishPage(page); // Close last page
   }
   pdf_doc.writeTo(fout);
   pdf_doc.close();
   //...
   //...
```

Helper function

```
    function PdfDocument.Page getNextPage(PdfDocument pdf_doc, PdfDocument.Page previous_page){
       pdf_doc.finishPage(previous_page); //Closes Previous page
       PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(595, 842, 1).create(); 
       return pdf_doc.startPage(pageInfo); //Begins New page
    }
```

Comment: In drawText first parameter you have given line so what is line here it requires line 9nly but you have declared it as array of string. Should I give line[i]

Comment: @Giddy Naya  Suppose if my text doesn't have any nextline and is a continuous one. Then how will I get MultiLine or multipage issues?, even if I use StaticLayout it solves the problem of multiline but not multipage